# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.awt.Image in android

Tags: java, android

I am facing the following issue in Android.

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                   Process: pkg.demo, PID: 22090
>                                                                   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.awt.Image
>                                                                       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:372)
>                                                                       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeInfoSetImpl.(RuntimeTypeInfoSetImpl.java:65)
>                                                                       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.createTypeInfoSet(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:133)
>                                                                       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.createTypeInfoSet(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:85)
>                                                                       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.(ModelBuilder.java:156)
>                                                                       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:93)
>                                                                       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:455)
>                                                                       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.(JAXBContextImpl.java:303)
>                                                                       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.(JAXBContextImpl.java:142)
>                                                                       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1174)
>                                                                       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:162)
>                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                       at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:202)
>                                                                       at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:363)
>                                                                       at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:574)
>                                                                       at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:522)

Comment: please share what you are trying to do and what you are implanted

Comment: Hi karan, I want implement Aadhar Auth API in android,

Comment: NoClassDefFoundError means  you are trying to access those class which is not available in your app or package. first check where that error redirect you .

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've edited your question. Please note the difference between _Android_ and _Android Studio_. _Android_ is the operating system; _Android Studio_ is the IDE, the tool you use to write Android code. Also, when asking questions here, it often helps to provide a [mcve]. You can [edit] your question to add one.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of your problem is in the first line of the exception:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: pkg.demo, PID: 22090 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.awt.Image at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.

Android cannot find the class `java.awt.Image`. This is because Image is an AWT class; AWT is a toolkit that does not exist in Android.

This error originates at `com.sun.xml.bind.v2.modle.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl`. So, it seems you've added a library that relies upon AWT.

The solution is to see if this library has been ported to Android; then use the Android port.
If there is no port, you'll have to find another library.